# To analyse $f:\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ can I just analyse $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2 $?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

To analyse $f:\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ can I just analyse $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ ?

My question is why would a complex valued function have different properties than a real 2-valued function, since I can construct a isomorphism between the spaces $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{C}$. Can I define derivatives and integration in the same way because of this isomorphism?

I'm asking this specially because I'm studying Complex Analysis this semester, and read about the result "If $f:\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C} \in C^{1}$ then $f \in C^\omega$" and I'm wondering if there is an analog one for real 2-valued functions.

Comment: You will quickly find out in your course that differentiability for a complex function of a complex variable says much more than differentiability of a vector valued function of two real variables.

Comment: That's very exciting! I was afraid of a positive answer to my question.

Comment: While certain real variable techniques are very helpful in understanding complex analytic functions, ignoring the treasure trove of algebraic/geometric properties of the field $\mathbb C$ would be like Decca Records turning down a recording contract for the Beatles.

Comment: You can create an isomorphism between {1,2,3} and {tomato, lettuce, potato}, but you can't make much of a salad with the former.

Having isomorphisms in a certain restricted sense (for example, you probably mean a linear isomorphism) doesn't mean that the spaces and everything that we can make with them are the same thing. The word "isomorphism" sometimes is used very carelessly.

Comment: Understood. But if I could create a homeomorphism instead? Isn't what define equivalence between topological spaces, and being equivalent wouldn't they have the same open sets, closed sets and continuous functions?

Comment: @Alnitak Correct. That's why the theory of continuous functions on $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{C}$ is the same, for example. Note however that the derivative of a complex function, for example, is defined by the limit of $\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$. "Transfer" that to $\mathbb{R}^2$. We already have a question: what is $\frac{1}{(x,y)}$?

Comment: @Alnitak: Since this question is closed, I added the answer I was writing to the question it was marked a duplicate of.

Comment: Note: I believe (English is not my first language) that possible (=correct) spellings are *analyse* or *analyze*. I won't comment on the reasons for preferring one over the other - may be related to geographical area?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Complex differentiability implies that the components $f_0,f_1$ are harmonic functions. That is a much stronger condition than real differentiability. (Being $C^\infty$)

Also, multiplication of complex numbers turn out to be useful. Analyticity extends naturally based on that.